# How to get message from sql query results using JDBC?

Tags: java, sql-server, t-sql, jdbc, ssms

I'm executing a sql server transaction query using JDBC. What I would like to do is to get the number of rows affected by every single command row in the query and print it. What I would like to obtain is like the message we can see in the Message Pane of sql-server. In this case:
https://ibb.co/1zTKXDz

I tried to use the function getWarnings() but it only shows me the first row ("1", the number of rows affected by the first operation inside the TRANSACTION) of what I want and from the second one on its value is null and I cannot understand why.

```
// Create and execute an SQL statement that returns some data.
                String SQL = "DECLARE @old nvarchar(13)\r\n" + 
                        "SET @old = 'UR0000325F001'\r\n" + 
                        "\r\n" + 
                        "BEGIN transaction MyT1\r\n" + 

                        "       UPDATE BERA7.dbo.MG89_LIFOART     SET MG89_CODART_MG66 = @old WHERE MG89_CODART_MG66 =@old\r\n" + 
                        "       UPDATE VIBO7.dbo.MG89_LIFOART     SET MG89_CODART_MG66 = @old WHERE MG89_CODART_MG66 =@old\r\n" + 
                        "       UPDATE VITM7.dbo.MG89_LIFOART     SET MG89_CODART_MG66 = @old WHERE MG89_CODART_MG66 =@old\r\n" + 
                        "       PRINT '--- MG1Q_ARTNOMENCLATURE ---'\r\n" + 
                        "       DELETE from BERA7.dbo.MG1Q_ARTNOMENCLATURE  WHERE MG1Q_CODART_MG66 =@old\r\n" + 
                        "       DELETE from VIBO7.dbo.MG1Q_ARTNOMENCLATURE     WHERE MG1Q_CODART_MG66 =@old\r\n" + 
                        "       DELETE from VITM7.dbo.MG1Q_ARTNOMENCLATURE     WHERE MG1Q_CODART_MG66 =@old\r\n" + 
                        "       PRINT '--- MG43_ARTPERS ---'\r\n" + 
                        "       DELETE from BERA7.dbo.MG43_ARTPERS      where MG43_CODART_MG66 =@old\r\n" + 
                        "       DELETE from VIBO7.dbo.MG43_ARTPERS             where MG43_CODART_MG66 =@old\r\n" + 
                        "       DELETE from VITM7.dbo.MG43_ARTPERS             where MG43_CODART_MG66 =@old\r\n" + 
                        "       PRINT '--- PD27_ANAFORMULE ---'\r\n" + 
                        "       DELETE FROM BERA7.dbo.PD27_ANAFORMULE\r\n" + 
                        "COMMIT transaction MyT1";

                stmt = con.createStatement();
                System.out.println(stmt.executeUpdate(SQL));

                SQLWarning warning = stmt.getWarnings();

                while (warning != null)
                {
                   warning = warning.getNextWarning();
                   System.out.println(warning);
                }
        }

    // Handle any errors that may have occurred.
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        e.getMessage();
    }

    finally {
        if (rs != null) try { rs.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
            if (stmt != null) try { stmt.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
            if (con != null) try { con.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
    }
```

What I expect is the number of row affected of each command.

Comment: One way would be to add addtional select count() - queries for each update and delete commands and excute those first.

Comment: @reporter thanks for your answer. Could you give me a practicle example of what you say?

Comment: For first delete query:  'Select count(*) from BERA7.dbo.MG89_LIFOART WHERE MG89_CODART_MG66 =@old'